# How can I inject files into League of Legends in C#?

Tags: c#

I used RAFLib-Plus(https://github.com/RichieSams/raflib-plus) to insert custom skin files.

RAFExtractor shows I replaced the files correctly,but the game crashed all the time when I try.

Here's the code:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string league_path = "C:\\Riot Games\\League of Legends\\RADS\\projects\\lol_game_client\\filearchives";
        RAFMasterFileList RAFMasterFileList = new RAFMasterFileList(league_path);
        List<string> entry = RAFMasterFileList.GetRAFFiles(league_path);
        entry.ForEach(raf_access);
    }

    private static void raf_access(string s)
    {
        bool content_changed = false;
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\DATA", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        //Console.WriteLine(s);
        RAFArchive RAFArchive = new RAFArchive(s);

        Dictionary<string, RAFFileListEntry> entries = RAFArchive.FileDictFull;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RAFFileListEntry> entry in entries)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                string correct_name;
                correct_name = fileName.Replace(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "").Replace("\\", "/").Substring(1);
                if( correct_name.ToLower() == entry.Key )
                {
                    content_changed = true;
                    if (RAFArchive.InsertFile(correct_name, File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), false))
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                        Console.Write(correct_name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(content_changed)
        {
            RAFArchive.SaveRAFFile();
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write(RAFArchive.RAFFilePath + " saved.");
        }

    }
```

and here's some of error log:

> 000016.279|  ERROR| Riot::RADS::Reader::DecompressZlib: Decompress ran out of sink buffer space: not all compressed data was consumed (11341 B read).
>   000016.279|  ERROR| Riot::RADS::Reader::ProjectListing::ArchiveFile::LogFailure: Failed to decompress archive file "DATA/Characters/Ashe/Skins/Base/Particles/Ashe_Base_Q_flying_shards.dds" from "C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/projects/lol_game_client/filearchives/0.0.1.29/Archive_1.raf.dat", version=0.0.1.29, compressionId=1112099930, offset=21023779, archiveSize=16880, entrySize=65664.
>   000016.279|  ERROR| Riot::RADS::Reader::ProjectListing::ArchiveFile::LogCompressedData: 78 9C EC 7D 0D 74 13 D7 99 F6 D5 8C 6C EB C7 FA B1 8D B1 F9 CD 08 6C 04 38 C2 D0 C6 01 E7 07 29   x..}.t......l.........l.8......)

Comment: the error point to a failure in unpackacking the compressed files, perhaps wrong/corrupted files? Hard to tell with non-opensource software and most likely against the EULA.

Comment: Given the repo hasn't been updated in 4 years, it's more than possible that this method has been patched by Riot Games because it could be used for cheating or piracy of their micro transactions. If anything, you might be able to get help directly from the developer of RAFLib by opening an issue via GitHub: https://github.com/RichieSams/raflib-plus/issues

Comment: @bradbury9 I'm very sure files in fileEntries are fine. But I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: @Carrosive Thanks for told me that,I thought it's the worst situation if nobody response the issue. There's only few libraries to process RAF files.